# change web.config back to previous setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I have split my App_Code folder into VB and CS folders, to accommodate the two class files at compile time. I added the following to the web.config file to make it work.

```
 <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" defaultLanguage="C#">
    <codeSubDirectories>
        <clear/>
        <add directoryName="VBCode" />
        <add directoryName="CSCode" />
    </codeSubDirectories>
</compilation>
```

I now want to remove the two folders and go back to a single vb only... IF I delete the above code from the web.config file I get the following error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The code subdirectory '/mysite/App_Code/VBCode/' does not exist.

Source Error: 


An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: E:\web\web.config    Line: 75
```

This is on a hosted site and it appears I don't have access to the machine.config or ability to view it?

How can I go back to previous configuration?

EDIT:

I understand the use of `<clear/>` but I'm looking to delete the folders from the site... refference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228265(VS.85).aspx

Comment: thanks - I didn't see why my question was voted down. Trying to figure out how to clean my my web.config file and remove un-needed code. - can't seem to figure out the error?

Comment: Your question is fair but most people are not using mixed mode. I'd have to write a few experiments and even then, I'm not sure if my code would match how you handling things. I am not sure if you can upload projects here but if you could point someone at a simple project in GitHub it would be simple to help you out. I love GitHub for sharing code and Visual Studio Online for private projects.